# How to make the MacBook Pro sleep when the lid is closed

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power

My MacBook Pro does not go to sleep when the lid is closed; I have to unplug the adaptor to make it sleep. When I plugin the power adaptor, it wakes up and keeps running even if the lid is closed.

What should I do to make it go to sleep when lid is closed? Here is the power adaptor settings:

[image]

the os is: Monterey 12.5.1, this is the mac info:

[image]

I know the macOS does not sleep because the macbook was hot and the cool system was very loud for hours(>8 hours).

Comment: Which macOS is installed on your MBP? What is your MBP's model? How do you figure out that it does not sleep as long as it is plugged in when its lid is closed? Is that the case even if, say, the lid is closed for at least half an hour? Why is there a warning sign (an exclamation mark) next to the battery settings in the power adapter settings screenshot you shared?

Comment: There is a warning triangle over the Battery section. What does that indicate? How do you know your Mac is not sleeping?